# Remove product and update checkout trigger continuously loading with Ajax at WooCommerce checkout

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, woocommerce

I am attempting to integrate a product removal feature along with triggering the checkout update for my WooCommerce setup. However, upon clicking the 'remove' option, the process seems to be stuck in a loading state. How can I ensure that the remove function and the checkout update trigger work seamlessly together using Ajax?

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'add_remove_product_link', 20, 3);

function add_remove_product_link($product_quantity, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);

    // Output existing quantity input
    echo $product_quantity;

    // Output Remove Product link with JavaScript click event
    echo '<br><a href="#" class="remove-product" data-product-key="' . $cart_item_key . '">Remove</a>';

    // Add JavaScript for handling the removal and updating the checkout
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('.remove-product[data-product-key="<?php echo $cart_item_key; ?>"]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var productKey = $(this).data('product-key');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        action: 'remove_product_and_update_checkout',
                        cart_item_key: productKey,
                        security: wc_checkout_params.update_order_review_nonce,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        // Update the checkout section without reloading the page
                        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// AJAX action to remove product from checkout and update checkout
add_action('wp_ajax_remove_product_and_update_checkout', 'remove_product_and_update_checkout');

function remove_product_and_update_checkout() {
    if (isset($_POST['cart_item_key'])) {
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item(sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($_POST['cart_item_key'])));
        WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
        wc_print_notices(); // Include this line to display notices if any

        // Output the updated cart totals and checkout section
        echo json_encode(array(
            'result' => 'success',
            'cart_totals' => WC()->cart->get_totals(),
            'html' => WC()->cart->cart_contents_count,
        ));
        die();
    }
}
```